# Is every convergent sequence in a topological vector space bounded?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

It is known that in a metric space, every convergent sequence is bounded. In a topological vector space (TVS), one also has the notion of [bounded sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set_(topological_vector_space)).

Here is my question:

> Is every convergent sequence in a topological vector space bounded?

---

Let $\{x_n\}$ in a TVS $X$ with $\lim x_n=0$. I think one can use the property that every neighborhood of $0$ is absorbing (and thus every finite set of $X$ is bounded) to show that $\{x_n\}$ is bounded. But I don't know how to do the general case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of points of a convergent sequence, together with the limit of the sequence (any limit if the space isn't Hausdorff), form a (quasi)compact set in any topological space. For if we have an open covering $\mathscr{U}$ of $S := \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{\lambda\}$, where $x_n \to \lambda$, then there is an $U_{\lambda} \in \mathscr{U}$ with $\lambda \in U_{\lambda}$. By definition of convergence, the set $E = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : x_n \notin U_{\lambda}\}$ is finite, and for every $e\in E$, we can choose an $U_e\in \mathscr{U}$ with $x_e \in U_e$. Thus the finite family $\{U_{\lambda}\} \cup \{ U_e : e \in E\}$ covers $S$. Since $\mathscr{U}$ was an arbitrary open covering of $S$, every open covering of $S$ has a finite subcover, i.e. $S$ is (quasi)compact.

Since neighbourhoods of $0$ are absorbing, (quasi)compact sets in a topological vector space are bounded. Let $K \subset X$ be (quasi)compact. If $U$ is any neighbourhood of $0$, there is a balanced open neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ with $V \subset U$, and

$$X = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} n\cdot V$$

since $V$ is absorbing. Thus $\{ n\cdot V : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is an open covering of $K$. By quasicompactness, it has a finite subcover $\{ n\cdot V : n \in F\}$. Since $V$ is balanced,

$$\bigcup_{n\in F} n \cdot V = (\max F)\cdot V,$$

and so $K \subset m\cdot V \subset m\cdot U$ for $m = \max F$. Since $U$ was arbitrary, this shows that $K$ is bounded.

And any subset of a bounded set is bounded, naturally.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I just don't see why the convergent sequence with *the* limit (limits for non Hausdorff space?) is compact and why quasi-compact sets are bounded. Would you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, let me edit, will take a couple of minutes.

Comment: Edit done. I really should learn to type faster ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaboration! I somehow came up with a proof with some basic properties of bounded sets. I 'm wondering if yours is actually more essential and I was just doing what you did.

Comment: The essence is not very different. For both arguments, it is crucial that once an open set contains the limit, there are only finitely many points left to capture. And the proof that a (quasi)compact set is bounded is not very different from the proof that a finite set is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to give a proof by just using some basic properties of bounded sets:

- If $A$ and $B$ are bounded in $X$, then $A+B$ is also bounded;
- Every finite subset of $X$ is bounded.

Suppose $x_n\to 0$. Let $V$ be a balanced $0$-neighborhood. There exists a positive integer $N$ such that $x_n\in V$ for $n>N$. Since $S_N:=\{x_n:n=1,\cdots,N\}$ is bounded (any finite set is bounded in a TVS), we have
$$
S_N\subset\lambda_1 V\subset (1+\lambda_1)V
$$
for some $\lambda_1>0$ where we use the fact that $tV\subset t'V$ if $t\leq t'$ for balanced $0$-neighborhoods. Note that $\{x_n\}_{n>N}\subset V\subset (1+\lambda_1)V$. Thus $\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is bounded.

Suppose in general $x_n\to x$ for some $x\in X$. Since $V$ is a $0$-nbhd iff $V+x$ is an $x$-nbhd, one has $x_n-x\to 0$. By what we have shown above, $\{x_n-x\}$ is bounded. Since $\{-x\}$ is bounded and 
$$
\{x_n\}=\{x_n-x\}+\{x\},
$$
We can conclude that $\{x_n\}$ is also bounded since the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of two bounded sets is bounded.